# Open in app button

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, ios-app

I often find myself in the situation that I browse the SE sites using my mobile browser (since I find it easier to keep multiple sites and questions open the same time) and then want the edit or answer a question.

I think the editor of the iOS app is much better then the mobile website experience, to I had like to open the question in the app to do the things I want to.

So I propose to create an `open in app` button on the mobile website, or another (easy) option to open a question in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have (say) the Guardian news app installed then when you click on links to their site your phone should already ask which application you want to open it in - my Android phone certainly does. This also allows you to always do this action.

I think the solution would be to associate Stack Exchange urls with the application (however that's done) and then let the user decide via their phone's OS which application to open the link in.